# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for check if `isset` `MySQL` data and check for int :

```
<input type="radio" name="lang"  value="1"
<?PHP if(isset(filter_var($__SQL__[0]['lang'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))){  
      echo ($__SQL__[0]['lang'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '');}?>
 />
```

But I See This Error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\editnews.php on line 56
```

how do can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of PHP. You are using `isset()`, which is not a function, but a [language construct](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/language-constructs-vs-built-in-functions/). You can only use it on simple variables, in PHP versions prior to 5.5. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`.

That means that you need to do something like this:

```
// We'll check if $__SQL__[0]['lang'] exists and
// the filter_var succeeds.
if (isset($__SQL__[0]['lang']) && filter_var($__SQL__[0]['lang'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
    echo ($__SQL__[0]['lang'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is some PHP behind, the problem could be calling a function isset($var) in this way:

```
if(isset($var = getMyVar())) { ... }
if(isset(filter_var($__SQL__[0]['lang'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))){ .. }
```

Instead of this You should call it this way:

```
$var = filter_var($__SQL__[0]['lang'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if(isset($var)) { ... }
```

Problem causes also other similar functions (empty, is_a, is_null, etc).

Something that may cause some irritation is the fact that you can't use isset and empty with functions:

```
isset(myFunction())
empty(myFunction())

-> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context
```

the following is the correct way of checking function return values:

```
if (myFunction() !== null)  -> equivalent of isset($var)

if (myFunction() == true)   -> equivalent of !empty($var)
if (myFunction())           -> concise equivalent of !empty($var)

if (myFunction() == false)  -> equivalent of empty($var)
if (!myFunction())          -> concise equivalent of empty($var)
```

Reference link to [isset](http://kunststube.net/isset/) -